# Testing JavaScript readline with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I have a function called move that allows user to input an answer.

```
move:function() {
  print("Enter number between 1 - 9");                         
  var userInput = readline();
  counter++
}
```

My jasmine test looks like this

```
it("takes turn playing pieces", function() {
  counter = 2;                                                   
  game = new PlayGame();      
  game.move()

  expect(counter).toEqual(3)
}
```

**The error message:** ReferenceError: readline is not defined.
I feel the problem is that jasmine doesn't know what readline is. The fact that I'm looking to get a user input in a test suite doesn't seem right. What can I test instead?

---

and instead just see if I'm getting the correct output (which is why I'm testing counter. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `readline()` with method call `ui.readline()` (object ui is wrapper for methods like readline) - than in test you can spy on readline method:

```
spyOn(ui, 'readline');
```

After this change your code will be testable.